# How can i parse a JSON inside another JSON together?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

Hi i have a Json like below format .I want to replace the value of `text:"Sample Text"`    Sample text with a value from My array in js file.

**JSON Format**

```
    prx.xdata = {"cc":6,
            "symbols":[
                     {
                    "id":1,
                    "title":"news container",
                    "states":[
                            {"title":"Default State",
                            "background":"none",

                            "data":"[{\"name\":\"text\",\"type\":\"text\",\"lib\":\"common\",\"caption\":\"newsitem1\",
                            \"text\":\"Sample text\",\"textFont\":\"sans-serif,Helvetica Neue,Arial\",\"textSize\":\"16\",
                            \"textColor\":\"000000\",\"backgroundColor\":\"none\",\"width\":292,\"height\":257,\"textProperties\":[],
                            \"textAlign\":\"left\",\"enableShadow\":false,\"autoResize\":false,\"left\":8,
                            \"top\":21,\"vpos\":\"top\",\"hpos\":\"left\",\"visible\":true,\"id\":\"box-2\",
                            \"groups\":[],\"zindex\":2001,\"wtype\":\"fixed\",\"htype\":\"fixed\",\"opacity\":\"1\"},

                            {\"name\":\"text\",
                            \"type\":\"text\",\"lib\":\"common\",\"caption\":\"news item2\",\"text\":\"Sample text\",\"textFont\":\"sans-serif,Helvetica Neue,
                            Arial\",\"textSize\":\"16\",\"textColor\":\"000000\",\"backgroundColor\":\"none\",\"width\":301,\"height\":257,\"textProperties\":[],
                            \"textAlign\":\"left\",\"enableShadow\":false,\"autoResize\":false,\"left\":300,\"top\":21,\"vpos\":\"top\",\"hpos\":\"left\",
                            \"visible\":true,\"id\":\"box-3\",\"groups\":[],\"zindex\":2002,\"wtype\":\"fixed\",\"htype\":\"fixed\",\"opacity\":\"1\"},

                            {\"name\":\"text\",\"type\":\"text\",\"lib\":\"common\",\"caption\":\"news item3\",\"text\":\"Sample text\",
                            \"textFont\":\"sans-serif,Helvetica Neue,Arial\",\"textSize\":\"16\",\"textColor\":\"000000\",
                            \"backgroundColor\":\"none\",\"width\":292,\"height\":257,\"textProperties\":[],\"textAlign\":\"left\",
                            \"enableShadow\":false,\"autoResize\":false,\"left\":601,\"top\":21,\"vpos\":\"top\",\"hpos\":\"left\",
                            \"visible\":true,\"id\":\"box-4\",\"groups\":[],\"zindex\":2003,\"wtype\":\"fixed\",
                            \"htype\":\"fixed\",\"opacity\":\"1\"},

                            {\"name\":\"text\",\"type\":\"text\",
                            \"lib\":\"common\",\"caption\":\"news item4\",\"text\":\"Sample text\",
                            \"textFont\":\"sans-serif,Helvetica Neue,Arial\",\"textSize\":\"16\",\"textColor\":\"000000\",
                            \"backgroundColor\":\"none\",\"width\":298,\"height\":257,\"textProperties\":[],
                            \"textAlign\":\"left\",\"enableShadow\":false,\"autoResize\":false,\"left\":901,\"top\":21,
                            \"vpos\":\"top\",\"hpos\":\"left\",\"visible\":true,\"id\":\"box-5\",\"groups\":[],\"zindex\":2004,\"wtype\":\"fixed\",
                            \"htype\":\"fixed\",\"opacity\":\"1\"}]",

                            "history":[],"dimensions":["1200","300"],"id":"a8d0d79e-1921-4f7e-a229-75e5b1602881"
                        }]
                    ,"sort":0,
                    "customguides":{"horizontal":[],"vertical":[]},
                    "grid":{"col_number":3,"col_width":80,"gutter_width":20,"margins":10}
                        }]
                    };

prx.xdata_str = JSON.stringify(prx.xdata);
```

I want to replace the value of "Sample text " in this path

```
symbols[0].states[0].data[0].text  with value from News array.
```

**Problem is here
symbols[0].states[0].data   this data is another JSON ,so am not able to parse that data.**

**Please check my Js code**

```
function yourJsFunction(arr){

   var b=arr.toString().split(',');


    var News =new Array();
    News=b;

    var jsondata = JSON.parse(prx.xdata);
   //alert(jsondata.symbols[0].states[0].data);
    var data=new Array();
    data=jsondata.symbols[0].states[0].data;
   // alert(data);
    var newData=JSON.parse(data);
    newData[0].text=News[0];
    newData[1].text=News[1];
    newData[2].text=News[2];
    newData[3].text=News[3];
    alert(newData[0].text);
//This alert showing my updated json.But when i click ok in alert the webview showing previous Json

     jsondata.symbols[0].states[0].data= JSON.stringify(newData);

    prx.xdata = JSON.stringify(jsondata);
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
       // document.write(arr[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: That's called a JInception

Comment: An Inception of JSon. Just kidding.

Comment: @Navi you have so many unclosed strings in `prx.xdata` ... your strings are not escaped properly... go to http://jshint.com and copy paste your whole `prx.xdata` you will see..

Answer (score -1):

`var x = "{a: 'a', b: 'b'}"` this is an json string

`var o = eval('"' + x + '"')` o is json object, parsed.

Comment: what are trying to say??am new in javascript please explain

Comment: i am trying to tell you how to parse json string into json object. then you can modify 'text' field and stringify it.

Comment: @sg3s he want replace one property in a json string, so i though parse-modify-stringify is what he wants. he seems know aboud stringify, then i told him how to parse json string.